# How do i page using forms with the Codeigniter framework?

Tags: codeigniter, uri, segment

I'm using the Codeigniter framework and am in the process of creating a registration form. The registration process is completed in multiple steps- for which I've created different views.

What I have a problem with is making the controller read that I've continued to a new step. I tried solving this by posting the form to `index.php/controller/2` but as I reach the page I get a 404 error stating

> The page doesn't exist.

I've loaded the URI helper so I don't quite understand where the problem lies.

All help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By submitting the form to `index.php/controller/2` you're effectively saying

- Load /application/controllers/Controller.php
- Instantiate class Controller
- Run Controller::2()

I suspect you don't have a method named 2, and you want to pass two as an argument to a method which handles step 1. Which might be `/controller/register` or similar.

You need to submit your form to `index.php/controller/method/2` and inside `method` check which step you're on using `$this->uri->segment(2)`

Ideally, create a different method for each step as it'll better separate the logic. For example

```
class Registration {
    function step_1() {}
    function step_2() {}
}
```

Which will allow you to call `index.php/registration/step_1/` and `index.php/registration/step_2/` for example.

You may also wish to use the Session class to set variables indicating which stages are complete to prevent people skipping to other stages by typing in the URL.

Comment: ofc it was that simple, funny thing is i read the manual like 10 times, and it clearly says example.com/class/function/ID but sometimes u get that tunnel vision and u dont get shit... :P
thx alot for the help btw :)